# Arduino Nano, nodeJS serial

Tags: serial, node.js

I tried to make a 2 way communication between my Arduino and a PC(running linux mint) using NodeJS:
My Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) Serial.println(Serial.readString()+"\r");
}
```

My NodeJS code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0',{
  baudRate: 9600,
  parity: 'none',
  stopBits: 1,
  flowControl: false,
  parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n')
});

port.on('open',function(){
  setInterval(() => port.write('Test'),1000);
});

port.on('data',(data) => console.log(data.toString()));
```

There is possible encoding error, but I cannot seem to find and fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Basicly it outputs "TestTestTest" with random length

Comment: What's more if I use Arduino code to send the data like Serial.println("Test"), and use readline('\n') I get correct results

Comment: Weird. For me, Arduino's `Serial.println()` plays well with serialport's `readline("\r\n")`.

Comment: Is this your code, or the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to revert to sending single bytes. Line oriented
protocols work well with both Arduino and Node.js. The only difficulty
is that you have to *decide* what line terminators you want to use, and
then *consistently* use them.

I tend to use CR for the PC → Arduino stream and CRLF for Arduino
→ PC. Using different line terminators is kind of odd, but this
convention plays well with terminal emulators: the emulator usually
sends CR when you hit `<Enter>`, and expects CRLF in return. Also,
Arduino's `Print::println()` sends CRLF.

Here is a simple test demonstrating this convention. Node.js side:

```javascript
var SerialPort = require('serialport'),
    port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyACM0', {
        baudRate: 9600,
        parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n')
    });

port.on('open', () => setInterval(() => port.write('Test\r'), 1000));
port.on('data', console.log);
```

Notice the different line terminators in `readline()` and `write()`.

The Arduino side:

```c++
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    static char buffer[128];
    static size_t pos;

    if (Serial.available()) {
        char c = Serial.read();
        if (c == '\r') {                       // line terminator
            buffer[pos] = '\0';                // terminate the string
            Serial.print(F("Arduino received: "));
            Serial.println(buffer);            // echo received message
            pos = 0;                           // reset buffer position
        } else if (pos < sizeof buffer - 1) {  // regular character
            buffer[pos++] = c;                 // buffer it
        }
    }
}
```

Here you may notice that Arduino has no equivalent of
`parsers.readline()`, so I had to implement it (comparing the incoming
character to `'\r'`). Note that explicit buffering of the incoming
message is a standard way of handling line-oriented protocols on
Arduino. `Stream::readString()` does not work well for this purpose, as
it waits for incoming bytes until it times out.
`Stream::readStringUntil()` may work better, but I prefer to avoid it
just because it returns a `String`, which relies on heap allocation.

Comment: Well, this code works great, but you forget that the content of the "previous" buffer stays in the array, which results in results like: "Arduino received: Testest"

Comment: @Berrigan: Oops! I forgot to properly terminate the string. Fixed. Now it works. The previous content of the buffer is now irrelevant, as only the contents before the first `'\0'` is considered to be part of the "string". After a complete string is received, the buffer is reset by the statement `pos = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue by using pure bytes, and then casting the response to the string in nodeJS, I post the codes in case anyone needs them:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0',{
  baudRate: 9600,
  parity: 'none',
  stopBits: 1,
  flowControl: false,
//  parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n')
});

function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

port.on('open',() => {
  setInterval(() => port.write('Test'),500);
});

port.on('data',(data) => {
  console.log(ab2str(data));
});
```

And the Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) Serial.write(Serial.read());
}
```